# How to Generate WSDL file in a java code but not using IDe

Tags: java, wsdl

I have many services/clases, I have to write a code that will generate a wsdl from a directory pick a service/java class, and generate wsdl.

e.g.

```
For(File file in Filew)
{
    file.generatewsdl(path,name); // for every class/service
}
```

Just like for all java clases or wevservice.. I don't have to explicitly generate wsdl from IDE, if any new service add then it will genere wsdl on run the program

Comment: Are you asking how to implement that `.generatewsdl(path,name)`?

Comment: Yes,  to generate wsdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Apache CXF tool "java2wsdl" may help you.

Here's the link : https://cxf.apache.org/docs/java-to-wsdl.html